# BodyFrame Class incompatible as argument of constructor for DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator

Tags: drake

I am using pydrake with the urdf of HSR from Toyota.

I want to use the DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator class.

When I tried to initialize the solver, I passed a BodyFrame class as the frame parameter of the constructor.

It gives the following incompatibility error

```
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. pydrake.manipulation.planner.DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator(robot: pydrake.multibody.plant.MultibodyPlant_[float], frame_E: pydrake.multibody.tree.Frame_[float], time_step: float, parameters: pydrake.manipulation.planner.DifferentialInverseKinematicsParameters, robot_context: pydrake.systems.framework.Context_[float] = None, log_only_when_result_state_changes: bool = True)

Invoked with: <pydrake.multibody.plant.MultibodyPlant_[float] object at 0x7f0633be88b0>, <BodyFrame_[float] name='hand_palm_link' index=31 model_instance=2>, <pydrake.manipulation.planner.DifferentialInverseKinematicsParameters object at 0x7f0633be8630>, 0.01, <pydrake.systems.framework.LeafContext_[float] object at 0x7f0633be84b0>, True
```

How I acquired the BodyFrame:

```
gripper = plant.GetBodyByName('hand_palm_link')
gripper_frame = gripper.body_frame()
```

and the `gripper_frame` was passed into the constructor as the `frame_E: drake::multibody::Frame<double>` argument specified in the python doc.

It is my understanding that BodyFrame is a child class of the Frame class since you can get a BodyFrame from a Frame object.

note: the result is the same when I used `plant.GetFrameByName('hand_palm_link')`

I have searched the doc and failed to find a way to expand a BodyFrame class into a Frame class

It could also be the `pydrake.systems.framework.LeafContext_[float]` that mismatched with `pydrake.systems.framework.Context_[float]` but I have already tested with a default context and the error persisted.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I am not well versed in drake enough to know how to get a Frame object associated with a specific link directly. Any help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only a quick glance (so I might be mistaken), it looks like `time_step` and `params` are being passed in the wrong order.  Try swapping them?